# If Button Pressed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to have an If statement that looks if a button has been pressed?

Thanks a lot!

```
    if(ButtonPressedStatement) {
      //Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (button.isSelected) {
        //
    }
```

**Edit**

To force button to keep its state, i use:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = ![sender isSelected];
}
```